# Symfony3 clone says not object

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I can't clone array collection object because it says it is not an object.

This is my action here:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($post);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\PostType', $post);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    var_dump($post->getPostImages()); // object
    // $original_images = clone $post->getPostImages();    says not object
    $original_images = $post->getPostImages();

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $postImages = $post->getPostImages();
        $post->setPostImages([]);
        var_dump($original_images); // not same as 1st dump
        die;

        foreach ($postImages as $image) {
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$image->guessExtension();
            if ($image->move(
            $this->container->getParameter('post_image').$post->getTitle(),
            $fileName)) {
                // $images[] = $fileName;
              $post->addPostImage(array('fileName' => $fileName));


            }
        }
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('post_edit', array('id' => $post->getId()));
    }

    if ($this->checkAction($post)) {
        return $this->checkAction($post);
    }

    return $this->render('post/edit.html.twig', array(
        'post' => $post,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The 1st var dump returns this:

```
object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#380 (1) { ["elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["fileName"]=> string(36) "ba2a3dd44902cc4411e6508015f026a3.png" } } }
```

When I try to clone the object I get this:

```
Error: __clone method called on non-object
```

And the 2nd var dump returns this (after submitting the form) :

```
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#14 (7) {
    ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    string(34) "Screenshot_2016-06-20_14-28-36.png"
    ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    int(610945)
    ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
    int(0)
    ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpoY3L5i"
    ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
    string(9) "phpoY3L5i"
  }
}
```

Update #1: 
The form builder:

```
    <?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('content')
            ->add('postImages', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Post Image', 'multiple' => true, 'data_class' => 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection', 'required' => false))
        ;
            }
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Post'
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see you `AppBundle\Form\PostType` code?

Comment: Here is the github link https://github.com/akyllax/flamerobin_website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently moving:

```
$original_images = $post->getPostImages();
```

Above:

```
$editForm->handleRequest($request);
```

Did the trick, now the code looks like this:

```
$deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($post);
$editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\PostType', $post);
$original_images = $post->getPostImages();
$editForm->handleRequest($request);
```

Comment: Hmm.  Is it really working because handleRequest is what is mapping any posted data.  Was your intent to clone the original data or the posted data?  And off topic but try replacing var_dump with the Symfony dump.

Comment: I didn't know there was a symfony dump, thanks for that.
The thing is that I upload a file(or more) and on the edit form if you chose not to upload any files they will get replaced in the database with a empty array (I will basically lose the files). So I want to save everything I have in there and check if the user uploads anything, if he doesn't I will repopulate it with what was already in there, if he uploads another file I will add that next to what is already in there.